# What is the benefit of having a whole program contained in a class?

Tags: python, class

Sometimes, when looking at Python code examples, I'll come across one where the whole program is contained within its own class, and almost every function of the program is actually a method of that class apart from a 'main' function.

Because it's a fairly new concept to me, I can't easily find an example even though I've seen it before, so I hope someone understands what I am referring to.

I know how classes can be used outside of the rest of a program's functions, but what is the advantage of using them in this way compared with having functions on their own?

Also, can/should a separate module with no function calls be structured using a class in this way?

Comment: also start to think about `gc`

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing an example.  It is certainly true that many people who come to Python from other more class-focused languages (like Java) often tend to overuse classes, so sometimes you will see code forced into a class when there was no need for that.  But, again, it's hard to say in general, because it depends on the particular situation.  There is no special reason to put everything in a class, nor any special reason to take everything out of classes; you put stuff in classes if you want what classes give you (e.g., organization of data nad methods in a separate namespace).

Comment: Something similar that I've seen is the use of a class which inherits from Frame being used to surround a whole program using tkinter. I'm not sure if this is a tkinter-specific thing or another example of what I talk about in my question. If anyone needs an example of this, I'll edit my post to contain one when I can (currently in the car).

Comment: In Tkinter is for more readable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A *module* is preferred when it is a collection of pure functions i.e. no shared state like module level variables. A big *class* is often used when there are multiple functions operating on a shared state.

In Python scripts, you will often see the pattern of the main function being just the instantiation of a class and calling a method for e.g [youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/__main__.py). This is done for various reasons:

- Can instantiate multiple objects without mixing state. It is easier to make it threadsafe.
- Classes can be inherited or composed (for e.g. see [BaseHTTPRequestHandler](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/http/server.py#L139)
- Classes have more features than modules like constructors, iteration support etc.

In general, classes offer more power with slight added complexity. Some people prefer functions for simplicity esp in the case of one-time scripts. The tradeoff is upto the developer and both are valid options in Python.

Answer (score 1):

A program often has to maintain state and share resources between functions (command line options, dB connection, etc). When that's the case a class is usually a better solution (wrt/ readability, testability and overall maintainability) than having to pass the whole context to every function or (worse) using global state.

Comment: For smaller scripts, I do not see much difference in using class methods and instance state vs. module-level functions and module-level (i.e. global) state.

Comment: @fbmd: unit testing comes to mind... But yes, for one-shot simple scripts you may not care that much.